# Does hashing a weak hash with a stronger hash make it secure?

Tags: hash, provable-security

If you made a hash function that worked like this:

SHA(std::hash(T input)

Would it be a secure hash? The reason I am asking is that std::hash provides a template input, which is much more convenient than the alternative provided by Crypto++, which requires a string input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cryptographic hash function should be collision resistant, i.e., nobody should be able to find two inputs having the same hash value. For non-cryptographic hash functions (like std::hash) this is *not* required, so someone might be able to find two inputs having the same output on std::hash.

Always ask yourself: What happens if you apply SHA to these outputs? Do you get a collision of your construction?